# Should I go for a table layout to create this?

Tags: linguistics, english

I have this in a printed book and I want to create the same in LaTeX.

[image]

Should I use two tables, one for the left and one for the right side? should I set hidden borders on the tables except the outer border? or is there a different way of obtaining this kind of layout. Any suggesdtion would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i looks like wo very simple `tabular`, what is the acual tex question here? not clear what you mean by hidden borders, you don't need to hide anything, tex will no add rules unless you specify they are added.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. Sorry I may have asked a silly question. I'm new to LaTeX. I'm going to read the entire `tabular` documentation if needed but I wanted to know what to use so I don't waste time looking at the wrong methods.

Comment: If I want to put a separate very small table below the left one, to fill that empty space, do I need to put the left tables in a minipage?

Comment: yes you could use a minipage for that or possibly simpler an outer 1-column tabular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this I guess

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,array}
\definecolor{bg}{gray}{.85}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small

\fcolorbox{black}{bg}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l*{3}{>{\itshape}l}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{CONTENT WORDS}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{examples}\\
 NOUNS   & person &place &thing\\
 NOUNS   & person &place &thing\\
 NOUNS   & person &place &thing
  \end{tabular}%
}%
\hfill
%
\fcolorbox{black}{bg}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l*{3}{>{\itshape}l}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{CONTENT WORDS}\\
\multicolumn{4}{l}{examples}\\
 NOUNS   & person &place &thing\\
 NOUNS   & person &place &thing\\
 NOUNS   & person &place &thing\\
 PRONOUNS   & person &place &thing
  \end{tabular}%
}

  
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add some padding to the table cells?

Comment: @ZoltanKing there is already 6pt but try `\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}` before the tables.